# Openshift events table for the pod is empty

Tags: events, docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

Yesterday there were some restart of the container for one pod in my Openshift Origin environment.
But today when I am inspecting why those restarts, I went to see the events for the particular pod.
All I see is an empty table. Why this that?

```
oc v3.6.0-alpha.1+46942ad
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server <server>
openshift v1.4.1
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events have a time-to-live and are expired after a few hours (2, by default).  That prevents those events from filling up the etcd storage space.  You can alter the default config to set a longer interval, but this would only be recommended for small clusters.

From Openshift 3.1 Release Notes:

In master-config.yaml, add the following stanza to set the event TTL. If you are experiencing high event volume, set the TTL to a lower value like 15 minutes 15m. The default is two hours 2h

```
kubernetesMasterConfig:
  apiServerArguments:
    event-ttl:
    - "15m"
```

Comment: can you help in where exactly to change this value, tried myself couldn't find so far...